# How to make my button into a checkbox

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ngtable

I have ng-table with the hidden columns feature. It has a basic checkbox as the toggle. I designed it to look a little nicer but I cant get it to work.

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/48boN6pweZ4aJdqrHYJa?p=preview)

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="column.visible"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
     </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of Bootstrap's Button plugin.

Are you using Bootstrap at all for this? I just removed Bootstrap's javascript file and it worked.

If you need Bootstrap, you either need to make a custom build of it or remove the `data-toggle="buttons"` from your `div` and style it yourself.

Comment: how would i style them?

Comment: Just add the same style from the `[data-toggle="buttons"]` selector. The `active` class can be add using Angular. I made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AlexFigueiredoo/4pzacfd2/